# Storing Markdown content with indentations on MySQL using PrismaDB

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, markdown, prisma

Hello fellow React developers. I'm building a blog site with NextJS and Prisma. The problem is. When I load the Markdown content from a file, it loads everything perfectly fine with it's indentations, styling and etc. But whenever I try to load that content from Prisma database it messes up the styling and indentations.

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82NKV.jpg)

The left one is being loaded from Database and left one is being loaded from file.

Here is my prisma.schema file. I store the content with `@db.text` tag.

```
model Blog {
  id          String     @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
  title       String
  description String?
  image       String?
  content     String?    @db.Text
  author      User       @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    String
  comments    Comments[]
  categories  Category[]
}
```

I tried to convert the content to HTML with a library called showdown and store it in database like that but that still lacked the indentation even tho it got most of the styling right.

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyzEH.png)

Left one is from file and right one is from database.

How can I fix this? Any help will be appreciated.